# Plugin to commit hudson build artifact

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, hudson, build-automation, hudson-plugins

Are there any plugins available which will commit the build artifact back to SVN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the [svn publisher](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/SVN+Publisher) will meet your needs.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately Svn Publisher is not really finished and requires quite a bit more work before I can use it in anger.

I've found I can do what I need with a shell/cmd script executed as a build action (or of course post-build would work), although it's not really ideal. The script just uses standard svn command line functions and looks something like:

```
svn mkdir http://my.server:port/project/branches/buildArtifacts/${BUILD_ID}/ --username USERNAME --password PASSWORD -m "JIRA_ISSUE This is a commit message"

svn co http://my.server:port/project/branches/buildArtifacts/${BUILD_ID}/ BuildArtifacts --username USERNAME --password PASSWORD

cd BuildArtifacts
cp ../../build/${BUILD_ID}/*.xml .

svn add *

svn ci --username USERNAME --password PASSWORD -m "JIRA_ISSUE This is a commit message"
```

So, we create the new folder for the build artifacts in Subversion, check it out to a local (in-workspace) folder, copy what we want in, `svn add` those items then commit everything back.

Personally, I am still not sold on the benefit of having build reports in Subversion, but we need to have persistent storage of this information -- the Jenkins server isn't a good repository for it.

Writing a custom plugin or actually fixing Svn Publisher would be a better solution long term.

Comment: Any way to obfuscate the password or leverage the password protection inherent in Hudson's SVN checkout utility?